# Angular 2 perfect-scrollbar возможно ли переписать стили?

Tags: angular2

Плагин [angular 2 perfect-scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-perfect-scrollbar) нормально подключается к проекту, но возникла необходимость переписать некоторые его стили, что, к сожалению, оказалось невозможным. Пробовал подключать к главному файлу стилей(style.css) и непосредственно в стилях главного компонента(app.component.css), но работает только в том случае, когда переписываю оформление прямо в index.html, примерно вот таким образом:

```
  <style>
    .ps-scrollbar-x, .ps-scrollbar-y {
      background-color: #0b4a5f !important;
    }
  </style>
```

подскажите пожалуйста как справится с этой проблемой

Comment: если версия 4.3 попробуй так `::ng-deep .ps-scrollbar-x, .ps-scrollbar-y`, если ниже, то `/deep/`